# One Campaign record is not displaying in the list of all campaign

Tags: community

In the list of campaign only one record is not displaying . but when I am searching that record it is displaying.
Here is the screenshot regarding this problem.
[image]

Here 252_Ferrrari_NewSales_RomaEveningPreviews_190320 this record is not showing
but after searching this it is present.Due to what it could be ?
[image: image 2]

Comment: Can you add the screen shot of filters of the list view?

Comment: I am quite sure it is related with Ferrari filter. Please edit that and check the condition according to which it is filtering records BTW record which is not shown has 3 R's in name like Ferrrari???

Comment: Thankyou so much .I got It and my problem is resolved